# All elements of String() Array ToLower, using LINQ

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, string, tolower

How Can I set to lower all the elements of an string array using LINQ?

```
Dim fileExtensions() As String = {"Mp3", "mP4", "wMw", "weBM", Nothing, ""}

Dim ToLower_fileExtensions = fileExtensions().Select...
```

(not using For)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim ToLower_fileExtensions = From w in fileExtensions Select IF(w Is Nothing, Nothing, w.ToLower())
```

Comment: It works fine for normal strings but throws an exception for empty fields (Nothing, ""), can you please update it with the needed clausures ? I think I need to add a where clausule to check if the field is empty or not.

Comment: Done, thanks again: From w In fileExtensions Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(w) Select w.ToLower()

Comment: @ElektroHacker That would eliminate `Nothing`s; my edit would preserve them.

Answer (score 2):

The easy and efficient way:

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To fileExtensions.Length - 1
    fileExtensions(i) = fileExtensions(i).ToLower()
Next
```

Since you've asked for linq, this is less efficient since it needs to create a new collection:

```
fileExtensions = fileExtensions.Select(Function(str) str.ToLower()).ToArray()
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a simple and generic function I've did based on @dasblinkenlight solution:

```
Private Function ArrayToLower(ByVal [Array] As IEnumerable) As IEnumerable

    Return From str In [Array] _
            Select If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(str), _
                      String.Empty, _
                      str.ToLower())

End Function
```

PS: Nice to convert it to a extension